# Remove/add discord roles to a person

Tags: python, discord.py, command, bots, pycord

I want to create a promote command which when issued it promotes the member to the next rank, but I can't get it to remove/add his roles

```
import discord
import os
from discord.utils import get

bot = discord.Bot(intents=discord.Intents.all())

admin = 990420666568278086

#roles
prospect = 869470046953537546
member = 869470100061814784
patched = 1003733917704134737

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"{bot.user} is ready and online!")

@bot.slash_command(name="promote", description = "Promote people to the next rank")
async def promote(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    if ctx.author.get_role(admin):
        if user.get_role(prospect):
            await user.remove_roles(prospect)
            await user.add_roles(member, patched)

bot.run("DISCORD-TOKEN")
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refering to [discord.Member.add_roles](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.add_roles) and [discord.Member.remove_roles](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.remove_roles). Both of them are taking [discord.Role](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#role) as parameter. Hence your code should look like `user.remove_roles(guild.get_role(prospect))` where `guild.get_role(prospect)` is returning [discord.Role](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#role)

This is what your code should looks like to make it works. Happy coding!

```py
async def promote(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    guild=ctx.guild
    if ctx.author.get_role(admin):
        if user.get_role(prospect):
            await user.remove_roles(guild.get_role(prospect))
            await user.add_roles(guild.get_role(member), guild.get_role(patched))
```

Comment: The first part here is wrong. The documentation for ``Member.get_role`` clearly states that it returns None if the user doesn't have a role with that ID. Not only is OP's if-statement good enough (None is falsy), yours doesn't even work. If the user doesn't have the role, it returns None, and ``None.id`` will raise an error.